# How to control the page before closing the window

Tags: javascript, jquery, window, window.onunload

I am using the function

```
 window.onbeforeunload = function(){
  if(sessionStorage.hasOwnProperty("teststatred")){
            validNavigation = true;
            leave_message = "You are in the middle of the test, Are you sure do you want to close the window?"
        }
        if (validNavigation)
        {
            if (!e) e = window.event;              
            e.cancelBubble = true;
            e.returnValue = leave_message;               
            if (e.stopPropagation) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                e.preventDefault();
            }             
            return leave_message;
        }
 }
```

This function will display a window of two buttons: `Leave this page` and `Stay on this page`.
How can I execute a function when the user clicks on `Leave this page` or 'Stay on this page'?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you *cannot,* because the only way would be to use `confirm(), alert(), or prompt()` and they will all be ignored:

**'Since 25 May 2011, the HTML5 specification states that calls to window.showModalDialog(), window.alert(), window.confirm(), and window.prompt() methods may be ignored during this event.'**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onbeforeunload?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fwindow.onbeforeunload

However, it *does* say *may,* so it wouldn't hurt to give it a try and `prompt` something.

Comment: How can we find the buttons `leavethispage` and `stayonthispage` and how can we assign click events